# Understanding Parser Combinator ~ Output

Tags: scala

Reading [DSLs in Action](http://www.manning.com/ghosh/), I saw this code for the `Sequential Combinator`:

```
def ~ [U](p: => Parser[U]): Parser[~[T, U]] =
(for(a <- this; b <- p) yield new ~(a,b)).named("~")
```

What is the meaning of the return type: `Parser[~[T, U]]`?

Is the return type a `Parser` containing a type that's the result of applying `~` to arguments of type `T` and `U`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `~` is basically a tuple type that allows an infix notation. So the returned parser in the question parses a type that is isomorphic to `(T,U)`. The infix notation allows to write the following:

```
def intParser: Parser[Int] = ???
def intPair: Parser[~[Int,Int]] = intParser ~ intParser
def product: Parser[Int] = intPair ^^ {case f1 ~ f2 => f1 * f2}
```

Or in one line, as it's usually done:

```
def product: Parser[Int] = intParser ~ intParser ^^ {case f1 ~ f2 => f1 * f2}
```

Or maybe a bit more sane, with the numbers separated by a `*`:

```
def product: Parser[Int] = intParser ~ ("*" ~> intParser) ^^ {case f1 ~ f2 => f1 * f2}
```

Note that `~>` drops the left hand side.